# C++ Wunused-variable with std::uniqe_ptr

Tags: c++, gcc

```
#include <memory>
int main() {
  std::unique_ptr<int> i = nullptr;
return 1;
}
```

Why won't this give me a `-Wunused-variable` warning (yes, they are enabled)?

(gcc version 7.3.1 20180303 (Red Hat 7.3.1-5) (GCC))

Cheers & thanks,

meru

Comment: Because this warning is not issues for objects with non-trivial constructors / destructors maybe?

Comment: ... because defining a variable of a non-trivial type might have side effects.

Comment: Ah, of course - silly me! Thanks :)